# What are the unit's of r in the equation r=mv/Be?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I apologise for the incredibly basic question, but could anyone let me know the units of r (e.g. are they metres, millimetres, centimetres?) As my A-level physics teacher was incredibly inconsistent when describing this and there is nothing in the book on this point

Comment: When speed is given in feet per second, the radius may be in feet. It depends on what units the other quantities are in.

Comment: What is the meaning of these symbols? Are we supposed to read your mind?

Comment: @Pirx No need to get snarky.  This is a very familiar equation to physicists.

Comment: Not snarky, just a stickler for precision. I am aware of this equation and the conventional meaning of its symbols.

Comment: A-level science is generally taught using [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Base_units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know is that it has units for a length-scale.

If you put all numbers in in SI-units (meter, seconds, kilograms, Kelvin, Amps etc) you *will* get an SI-unit out. So only SI-units for the variables, and $r$ will come out in the SI-unit of length: *meters*.

As the comment to the question describes, your question therefore can't be answered unless you tell the units of each value you plug into the formula. And honestly, if you know each unit that is put in, then you should be able to easily divide and multiply to see what the final unit of that calculation turns out to be.